# How to use sonarcloud with travis?

Tags: unit-testing, jenkins, github, sonarqube, sonarcloud

## Description

We are already using sonarqube locally and we want to use it for our open source projects.

This is an example OpenSource project we are trying to setup:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/@yeutech-lab/accept-dot-path
- https://github.com/yeutech-lab/accept-dot-path

Using `dev` branch we have followed the [documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/sonarcloud/) and the build is failing:

- https://travis-ci.org/yeutech-lab/accept-dot-path/jobs/396729046

### Reproduction

- [Failing job on travis](https://travis-ci.org/yeutech-lab/accept-dot-path/jobs/396729046)

This is my `sonar-project.properties`:

```
sonar.testExecutionReportPaths=reports/test-report.xml
sonar.projectKey=com.github.yeutech-lab.accept-dot-path
sonar.projectName=com.github.yeutech-lab.accept-dot-path
sonar.sources=src
sonar.exclusions=/src/**/tests/*.test.js
sonar.test.exclusions=/src/**/tests/*.test.js
sonar.dynamicAnalysis=reuseReports
sonar.javascript.jstest.reportsPath=coverage
sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths=coverage/lcov.info
```

This is my stage failing `.travis.yml`:

```
- stage: test
  if: branch IN (dev, master)
  node_js:
    - lts/*
    - 10
    - 8
  addons:
    sonarcloud:
      organization: "yeutech-lab"
  script:
    - npm run test
    - sonar-scanner -X -Dsonar.branch=${TRAVIS_BRANCH} -Dsonar.projectVersion=${SONAR_VERSION}
```

I have the following error:

```
26.52s$ sonar-scanner -X -Dsonar.branch=${TRAVIS_BRANCH} -Dsonar.projectVersion=${SONAR_VERSION}
06:30:58.836 INFO: Scanner configuration file: /home/travis/.sonarscanner/sonar-scanner-3.0.3.778/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
06:30:58.845 INFO: Project root configuration file: /home/travis/build/yeutech-lab/accept-dot-path/sonar-project.properties
06:30:58.931 INFO: SonarQube Scanner 3.0.3.778
06:30:58.931 INFO: Java 1.8.0_151 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
06:30:58.931 INFO: Linux 4.4.0-101-generic amd64
06:30:59.317 DEBUG: keyStore is : 
06:30:59.317 DEBUG: keyStore type is : jks
06:30:59.318 DEBUG: keyStore provider is : 
06:30:59.319 DEBUG: init keystore
06:30:59.321 DEBUG: init keymanager of type SunX509
06:30:59.534 DEBUG: Create : /home/travis/.sonar/cache
06:30:59.537 INFO: User cache: /home/travis/.sonar/cache
06:30:59.539 DEBUG: Create : /home/travis/.sonar/cache/_tmp
06:30:59.539 DEBUG: Extract sonar-scanner-api-batch in temp...
06:30:59.565 DEBUG: Get bootstrap index...
06:30:59.565 DEBUG: Download: https://sonarcloud.io/batch/index
06:31:00.321 DEBUG: Get bootstrap completed
06:31:00.323 DEBUG: Download https://sonarcloud.io/batch/file?name=sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-developer-7.3.0.13459-all.jar to /home/travis/.sonar/cache/_tmp/fileCache1590224166395973229.tmp
06:31:05.257 DEBUG: Create isolated classloader...
06:31:05.277 DEBUG: Start temp cleaning...
06:31:05.304 DEBUG: Temp cleaning done
06:31:05.304 DEBUG: Execution getVersion
06:31:05.310 DEBUG: Execution start
06:31:05.598 INFO: Publish mode
06:31:05.771 INFO: Load global settings
06:31:06.441 DEBUG: GET 200 https://sonarcloud.io/api/settings/values.protobuf | time=659ms
06:31:06.467 INFO: Load global settings (done) | time=697ms
06:31:06.485 INFO: Server id: AWHW8ct9-T_TB3XqouNu
06:31:06.502 DEBUG: Create : /home/travis/.sonar/_tmp
06:31:06.503 INFO: User cache: /home/travis/.sonar/cache
06:31:06.686 INFO: Load/download plugins
06:31:06.686 INFO: Load plugins index
06:31:06.806 DEBUG: GET 200 https://sonarcloud.io/api/plugins/installed | time=120ms
06:31:06.850 INFO: Load plugins index (done) | time=164ms
06:31:06.853 DEBUG: Download plugin 'authbitbucket' to '/home/travis/.sonar/_tmp/fileCache8382949818402309739.tmp'
06:31:06.972 DEBUG: GET 200 https://sonarcloud.io/api/plugins/download?plugin=authbitbucket&acceptCompressions=pack200 | time=118ms
06:31:07.480 DEBUG: Unpacking plugin authbitbucket
06:31:07.564 DEBUG: Download plugin 'scmgit' to '/home/travis/.sonar/_tmp/fileCache3430018907165592069.tmp'
06:31:07.688 DEBUG: GET 200 https://sonarcloud.io/api/plugins/download?plugin=scmgit&acceptCompressions=pack200 | time=123ms
06:31:07.936 DEBUG: Unpacking plugin scmgit
06:31:08.353 DEBUG: Download plugin 'github' to '/home/travis/.sonar/_tmp/fileCache5247411604780626227.tmp'
06:31:08.471 DEBUG: GET 200 https://sonarcloud.io/api/plugins/download?plugin=github&acceptCompressions=pack200 | time=116ms
06:31:08.885 DEBUG: Unpacking plugin github
06:31:09.011 DEBUG: Download plugin 'authgithub' to '/home/travis/.sonar/_tmp/fileCache1172914636956968383.tmp'
06:31:09.128 DEBUG: GET 200 https://sonarcloud.io/api/plugins/download?plugin=authgithub&acceptCompressions=pack200 | time=116ms
06:31:09.143 DEBUG: Unpacking plugin authgithub
06:31:09.164 DEBUG: Download plugin 'license' to '/home/travis/.sonar/_tmp/fileCache2891083593711587642.tmp'
06:31:09.280 DEBUG: GET 200 https://sonarcloud.io/api/plugins/download?plugin=license&acceptCompressions=pack200 | time=115ms
06:31:09.282 DEBUG: Unpacking plugin license
06:31:09.288 DEBUG: Download plugin 'scmmercurial' to '/home/travis/.sonar/_tmp/fileCache480957901258776338.tmp'
06:31:09.405 DEBUG: GET 200 https://sonarcloud.io/api/plugins/download?plugin=scmmercurial&acceptCompressions=pack200 | time=117ms
06:31:09.407 DEBUG: Unpacking plugin scmmercurial
06:31:09.411 DEBUG: Download plugin 'authmicrosoft' to '/home/travis/.sonar/_tmp/fileCache7929759057179488686.tmp'
06:31:09.528 DEBUG: GET 200 https://sonarcloud.io/api/plugins/download?plugin=authmicrosoft&acceptCompressions=pack200 | time=115ms
06:31:10.238 DEBUG: Unpacking plugin authmicrosoft
06:31:10.479 DEBUG: Download plugin 'abap' to '/home/travis/.sonar/_tmp/fileCache6155881230164947210.tmp'
06:31:10.596 DEBUG: GET 200 https://sonarcloud.io/api/plugins/download?plugin=abap&acceptCompressions=pack200 | time=115ms
06:31:10.714 DEBUG: Unpacking plugin abap
06:31:10.918 DEBUG: Download plugin 'csharp' to '/home/travis/.sonar/_tmp/fileCache6706825159734964118.tmp'
06:31:11.034 DEBUG: GET 200 https://sonarcloud.io/api/plugins/download?plugin=csharp&acceptCompressions=pack200 | time=115ms
06:31:11.279 DEBUG: Unpacking plugin csharp
06:31:11.422 DEBUG: Download plugin 'cpp' to '/home/travis/.sonar/_tmp/fileCache5652771019902212699.tmp'
06:31:11.539 DEBUG: GET 200 https://sonarcloud.io/api/plugins/download?plugin=cpp&acceptCompressions=pack200 | time=116ms
06:31:12.227 DEBUG: Unpacking plugin cpp
06:31:12.863 DEBUG: Download plugin 'flex' to '/home/travis/.sonar/_tmp/fileCache8167974862316719743.tmp'
06:31:12.982 DEBUG: GET 200 https://sonarcloud.io/api/plugins/download?plugin=flex&acceptCompressions=pack200 | time=115ms
06:31:13.237 DEBUG: Unpacking plugin flex
06:31:13.426 DEBUG: Download plugin 'go' to '/home/travis/.sonar/_tmp/fileCache4775478942526974201.tmp'
06:31:13.542 DEBUG: GET 200 https://sonarcloud.io/api/plugins/download?plugin=go&acceptCompressions=pack200 | time=116ms
06:31:14.679 DEBUG: Unpacking plugin go
06:31:15.380 DEBUG: Download plugin 'javascript' to '/home/travis/.sonar/_tmp/fileCache6735152755692319121.tmp'
06:31:15.497 DEBUG: GET 200 https://sonarcloud.io/api/plugins/download?plugin=javascript&acceptCompressions=pack200 | time=116ms
06:31:15.839 DEBUG: Unpacking plugin javascript
06:31:16.231 DEBUG: Download plugin 'java' to '/home/travis/.sonar/_tmp/fileCache4775164839730523442.tmp'
06:31:16.348 DEBUG: GET 200 https://sonarcloud.io/api/plugins/download?plugin=java&acceptCompressions=pack200 | time=117ms
06:31:16.921 DEBUG: Unpacking plugin java
06:31:17.871 DEBUG: Download plugin 'php' to '/home/travis/.sonar/_tmp/fileCache4310559658352997108.tmp'
06:31:17.989 DEBUG: GET 200 https://sonarcloud.io/api/plugins/download?plugin=php&acceptCompressions=pack200 | time=117ms
06:31:18.335 DEBUG: Unpacking plugin php
06:31:18.630 DEBUG: Download plugin 'plsql' to '/home/travis/.sonar/_tmp/fileCache4483462510508490361.tmp'
06:31:18.746 DEBUG: GET 200 https://sonarcloud.io/api/plugins/download?plugin=plsql&acceptCompressions=pack200 | time=116ms
06:31:18.873 DEBUG: Unpacking plugin plsql
06:31:19.120 DEBUG: Download plugin 'python' to '/home/travis/.sonar/_tmp/fileCache7976201852420985200.tmp'
06:31:19.236 DEBUG: GET 200 https://sonarcloud.io/api/plugins/download?plugin=python&acceptCompressions=pack200 | time=116ms
06:31:19.361 DEBUG: Unpacking plugin python
06:31:19.548 DEBUG: Download plugin 'security' to '/home/travis/.sonar/_tmp/fileCache4952173467535429371.tmp'
06:31:19.664 DEBUG: GET 200 https://sonarcloud.io/api/plugins/download?plugin=security&acceptCompressions=pack200 | time=116ms
06:31:19.782 DEBUG: Unpacking plugin security
06:31:19.930 DEBUG: Download plugin 'swift' to '/home/travis/.sonar/_tmp/fileCache7219239880236505170.tmp'
06:31:20.046 DEBUG: GET 200 https://sonarcloud.io/api/plugins/download?plugin=swift&acceptCompressions=pack200 | time=115ms
06:31:20.175 DEBUG: Unpacking plugin swift
06:31:20.422 DEBUG: Download plugin 'typescript' to '/home/travis/.sonar/_tmp/fileCache8846622888447642464.tmp'
06:31:20.539 DEBUG: GET 200 https://sonarcloud.io/api/plugins/download?plugin=typescript&acceptCompressions=pack200 | time=116ms
06:31:21.109 DEBUG: Unpacking plugin typescript
06:31:21.247 DEBUG: Download plugin 'tsql' to '/home/travis/.sonar/_tmp/fileCache6294671329122059465.tmp'
06:31:21.363 DEBUG: GET 200 https://sonarcloud.io/api/plugins/download?plugin=tsql&acceptCompressions=pack200 | time=116ms
06:31:21.480 DEBUG: Unpacking plugin tsql
06:31:21.723 DEBUG: Download plugin 'vbnet' to '/home/travis/.sonar/_tmp/fileCache2366356249389465444.tmp'
06:31:21.841 DEBUG: GET 200 https://sonarcloud.io/api/plugins/download?plugin=vbnet&acceptCompressions=pack200 | time=118ms
06:31:22.076 DEBUG: Unpacking plugin vbnet
06:31:22.169 DEBUG: Download plugin 'web' to '/home/travis/.sonar/_tmp/fileCache1192878208453770217.tmp'
06:31:22.286 DEBUG: GET 200 https://sonarcloud.io/api/plugins/download?plugin=web&acceptCompressions=pack200 | time=117ms
06:31:22.401 DEBUG: Unpacking plugin web
06:31:22.611 DEBUG: Download plugin 'xml' to '/home/travis/.sonar/_tmp/fileCache6491864581862163918.tmp'
06:31:22.728 DEBUG: GET 200 https://sonarcloud.io/api/plugins/download?plugin=xml&acceptCompressions=pack200 | time=116ms
06:31:22.955 DEBUG: Unpacking plugin xml
06:31:23.186 INFO: Load/download plugins (done) | time=16500ms
06:31:23.250 DEBUG: API compatibility mode is enabled on plugin Mercurial [scmmercurial] (built with API lower than 5.2)
06:31:23.491 DEBUG: Plugins:
06:31:23.492 DEBUG:   * Bitbucket Authentication for SonarQube 1.1.0.344 (authbitbucket)
06:31:23.493 DEBUG:   * SonarPLSQL 3.2.0.1753 (plsql)
06:31:23.493 DEBUG:   * SonarC# 7.2.0.5463 (csharp)
06:31:23.494 DEBUG:   * SonarSecurity 7.2.0.944 (security)
06:31:23.495 DEBUG:   * SonarJava 5.4.0.14284 (java)
06:31:23.495 DEBUG:   * SonarWeb 2.6.0.1053 (web)
06:31:23.496 DEBUG:   * SonarFlex 2.4.0.1222 (flex)
06:31:23.496 DEBUG:   * SonarXML 1.5.1.1452 (xml)
06:31:23.497 DEBUG:   * SonarTS 1.7.0.2828 (typescript)
06:31:23.498 DEBUG:   * SonarVB 5.1.0.442 (vbnet)
06:31:23.498 DEBUG:   * SonarSwift 3.3.0.2492 (swift)
06:31:23.499 DEBUG:   * GitHub 1.4.2.1027 (github)
06:31:23.500 DEBUG:   * SonarCFamily 5.1.0.10083 (cpp)
06:31:23.501 DEBUG:   * SonarPython 1.10.0.2131 (python)
06:31:23.501 DEBUG:   * GitHub Authentication for SonarQube 1.4.0.660 (authgithub)
06:31:23.501 DEBUG:   * Mercurial 1.1.1 (scmmercurial)
06:31:23.501 DEBUG:   * SonarGo 1.1.0.1612 (go)
06:31:23.501 DEBUG:   * Microsoft Authentication for SonarCloud 1.0.0.157 (authmicrosoft)
06:31:23.501 DEBUG:   * SonarTSQL 1.2.0.2539 (tsql)
06:31:23.501 DEBUG:   * SonarJS 4.1.0.6085 (javascript)
06:31:23.501 DEBUG:   * License for SonarLint 7.3.0.13459 (license)
06:31:23.504 DEBUG:   * Git 1.5.0.1160 (scmgit)
06:31:23.504 DEBUG:   * SonarPHP 2.13.0.3107 (php)
06:31:23.505 DEBUG:   * SonarABAP 3.6.0.1269 (abap)
06:31:23.543 INFO: Loaded core extensions: branch-scanner
06:31:23.544 DEBUG: Execution getVersion
06:31:23.545 INFO: SonarQube server 7.3.0
06:31:23.546 INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8" (analysis is platform dependent)
06:31:23.548 DEBUG: Work directory: /home/travis/build/yeutech-lab/accept-dot-path/.scannerwork
06:31:23.549 DEBUG: Execution getVersion
06:31:23.550 DEBUG: Execution execute
06:31:23.860 INFO: Installed core extension: branch-scanner
06:31:24.122 INFO: Installed core extension: branch-scanner
06:31:24.129 INFO: Process project properties
06:31:24.143 DEBUG: Process project properties (done) | time=14ms
06:31:24.158 INFO: Load project branches
06:31:24.278 DEBUG: GET 404 https://sonarcloud.io/api/project_branches/list?project=com.github.yeutech-lab.accept-dot-path%3Adev | time=116ms
06:31:24.282 DEBUG: Could not process project branches - continuing without it
06:31:24.285 INFO: Load project branches (done) | time=127ms
06:31:24.289 INFO: Load project pull requests
06:31:24.406 DEBUG: GET 404 https://sonarcloud.io/api/project_pull_requests/list?project=com.github.yeutech-lab.accept-dot-path%3Adev | time=115ms
06:31:24.407 DEBUG: Could not process project pull requests - continuing without it
06:31:24.410 INFO: Load project pull requests (done) | time=122ms
06:31:24.410 INFO: Load branch configuration
06:31:24.411 DEBUG: Not on a Bitbucket pipeline.
06:31:24.419 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
06:31:24.419 INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
06:31:24.419 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
06:31:24.419 INFO: Total time: 25.644s
06:31:24.518 INFO: Final Memory: 54M/188M
06:31:24.518 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
06:31:24.518 ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectLock
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:65)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:678)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.getComponentByType(ComponentContainer.java:281)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doBeforeStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:123)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:134)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:122)
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:48)
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:81)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:136)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:122)
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:132)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecuteTask(Batch.java:116)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:111)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:233)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedScanner.java:151)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.runAnalysis(Main.java:123)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:77)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.scan.DefaultInputModuleHierarchy
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:65)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:632)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:63)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectBuildersExecutor
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:65)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:632)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getMemberArguments(SingleMemberInjector.java:61)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.getMemberArguments(MethodInjector.java:100)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector$2.run(MethodInjector.java:112)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.decorateComponentInstance(MethodInjector.java:120)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.CompositeInjector.decorateComponentInstance(CompositeInjector.java:58)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.Reinjector.reinject(Reinjector.java:142)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ProviderAdapter.getComponentInstance(ProviderAdapter.java:96)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:63)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.plugins.github.PullRequestProjectBuilder
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:65)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:621)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.CollectionComponentParameter.getArrayInstance(CollectionComponentParameter.java:334)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.CollectionComponentParameter.access$100(CollectionComponentParameter.java:49)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.CollectionComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(CollectionComponentParameter.java:139)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:141)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:63)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.plugins.github.GitHubPluginConfiguration
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:65)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:632)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:63)
    ... 69 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.scan.MutableProjectSettings
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:65)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:632)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:63)
    ... 83 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.repository.ProjectRepositories
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:65)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:632)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:63)
    ... 97 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component interface org.sonar.scanner.scan.branch.BranchConfiguration
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:65)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:632)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getMemberArguments(SingleMemberInjector.java:61)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.getMemberArguments(MethodInjector.java:100)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector$2.run(MethodInjector.java:112)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.decorateComponentInstance(MethodInjector.java:120)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.CompositeInjector.decorateComponentInstance(CompositeInjector.java:58)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.Reinjector.reinject(Reinjector.java:142)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ProviderAdapter.getComponentInstance(ProviderAdapter.java:96)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:63)
    ... 111 more
Caused by: Project was never analyzed. A regular analysis is required before a branch analysis
06:31:24.545 DEBUG: Execution getVersion
06:31:24.545 DEBUG: Execution stop
The command "sonar-scanner -X -Dsonar.branch=${TRAVIS_BRANCH} -Dsonar.projectVersion=${SONAR_VERSION}" exited with 1.
store build cache
```

I have no clue what this error message is about, the same configuration work for our local sonarqube.

Can I have information on how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to directly analyze a branch whereas your project has not been created yet. This is why you get the following message:

> Project was never analyzed. A regular analysis is required before a
>   branch analysis

Fixing the situation is simple:

1. Go to your organization "Administration > Projects Management" page
2. Click on "Create Project" and set the project name and key (`com.github.yeutech-lab.accept-dot-path` in your case)

This should fix your issue.

Comment: Is there a way to do that using scripting? We are in env where we do not have desktop. (CI)

Comment: You need to do it only once, so there's no point in scripting this.

Comment: This is how I did : `curl -sS -X POST "https://${SONARCLOUD_LOGIN}@sonarcloud.io/api/projects/create" -d "name=${sonarId}&project=${sonarId}&organization=${scope}"`, the creation of the github project, travis and sonarcloud is done during a ci that is in charge of releasing opensource, the point was not to let human do it. Thanks your answer helped us understood the real probleme and was solved easely

Comment: having same error, but my analysis is on the master branch (sonar.branch.name=master). So I would expect sonar to create the project and not have this limitation here. "ERROR: Could not find branches. A regular analysis is required before creating branches".

Comment: "You need to do it only once, so there's no point in scripting this" => maybe once per project but in our case we've got hundreds of projects. Furthermore we don t have admin access.

Comment: After few tests I verified that for sonar v6.7 -> first analysis : parameter branch cannot be passed (even master...!), then once that specific call is made then branch.name=master or branch.name=myfeature is authorized. I ve tested without the parameter (hoping it would find the branch on its own) and it mixed up master and my feature altogether in the main sonar view (master). very inconvenient.